# Find the Frobenius!

Tags: code-golf, math

### Intro:

A Frobenius number is a number which cannot be made from numbers in a set.

For example, `43` is the Frobenius number of the set `{6, 9, 20}`, because you cannot get 43 from those numbers, and it is the largest number which cannot be made.

`42` is not a Frobenius number of the set `{6, 9, 20}`, because it can be made from 4 `6`'s and 2 `9`'s (`4*6 + 2*9 = 42`).

### Task and Specs:

Your task is, when given a list of numbers as input, find the Frobenius number.

You are guaranteed that there will always be at least two numbers in the input (if there's only 1 number in the input, the result will be infinite).

You are also guaranteed that all numbers are positive.

You only need to calculate up to and including `2^32 - 1`.

### Examples:

- `6, 9, 20` = `43`
- `4, 7` = `17`
- `10, 12` = `Infinity` or whatever value cannot be made last

You are NOT allowed to use built-ins (I'm looking at you, Mathematica).

Comment: `Mathematica, 15 bytes, ...` Oh, uh, nevermind.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57146/20260), which was also done [in the SO days](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3465392).